# Reading of 年 in いつもの年よりたくさん作っています

Tags: readings

> 熱中症にならないように飲み物を買う人が増えていて、飲み物の会社はいつもの年{とし}よりたくさん作っています。
>   The number of people buying drinks to avoid heat stroke is increasing, and the drinks companies are making a lot more than in usual years.

It took me a while to determine the true meaning of this sentence. When I first read it I got to いつもの年{とし}より and thought "usual old people". Then I got very confused. Eventually, I realised it must be "compared to usual years" and thought: Ah, it must be pronounced ねん rather than とし. I turned on the furigana and it was indeed とし.

Would you expect to read 年 as とし or ねん in this context? Secondly, would this sentence cause even a moments confusion to a fluent speaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私は、a fluent speaker です。

> ... 飲み物の会社はいつもの**年**よりたくさん作っています。

ＯＰの挙｛あ｝げた例文｛れいぶん｝と違｛ちが｝って、普通｛ふつう｝には上記｛じょうき｝のように「年」の上に[振り仮名]{ふりがな}はついていません。ＯＰの質問｛しつもん｝に対｛たい｝して振り仮名がない文｛ぶん｝を見｛っみ｝たときの条件｛じょうけん｝で回答｛かいとう｝します。
（普段｛ふだん｝、私は「ふりがな」とひらがなで書｛か｝くと思｛おも｝いますが、この回答の文をひらがなで書くと読｛よ｝みにくいことが分かりましたので敢｛あ｝えて漢字で書きなおしました。）

> Would you expect to read 年 as とし or ねん in this context?

例文｛れいぶん｝中｛ちゅう｝の「年」を、その前後｛ぜんご｝の文字と繋｛つな｝げて考｛かんが｝えると、意味｛いみ｝のありそうなフレーズは「いつもの年｛とし｝」と「いつもの年｛とし｝より」です。「いつもの年｛ねん｝」と「いつもの年｛ねん｝より」という読｛よ｝み方｛かた｝は無｛な｝しです（do not make sense）。従｛したが｝って、この文脈｛ぶんみゃく｝では（in this context）「年」に対する読｛よ｝みは「とし」しかありません。

> Secondly, would this sentence cause even a moments confusion to a fluent speaker?

ふりがなのないＯＰの例文を見たとき、「年」という文字が目に飛｛と｝び込｛こ｝んできますので、ＯＰが言うようにほんの瞬間｛しゅんかん｝ですが、どう読もうかと考｛かんが｝えます。この瞬間を to cause even a moments confusion と言うならＯＰの質問｛しつもん｝に対｛たい｝する答えは yes です。一般｛いっぱん｝にどう読もうかと考えたあと、「年」の字の前後に目を走｛はし｝らせます。前後の文字とつないで意味のありそうなフレーズは「いつもの年」と「年より」あるいは前後をまとめて「いつもの年より」です。いずれも「年｛ねん｝」とは読まないことが瞬間にわかります。この時点で混乱｛こんらん｝（confusion）は終｛お｝わりです。以上｛いじょう｝の作業｛さぎょう｝は、普通｛ふつう｝の人なら文｛ぶん｝を読み進｛すす｝めながら並行｛へいこう｝して行｛おこな｝っており、実際｛じっさい｝にそのフレーズを読んでいるときにはすでに「年｛とし｝」と読むことは決｛き｝まっています。

従って、ＯＰの２番目の質問に対しての答えは yes ですが、実際｛じっさい｝には支障｛ししょう｝はでません (not to cause any problem)。

私は、一般にどのようにしてこの種｛しゅ｝の混乱｛こんらん｝を防｛ふせ｝いでいるか少｛すこ｝しだけ例｛れい｝を挙｛あ｝げて説明｛せつめい｝します。

（１）ＯＰの例では、「いつもの年より」のフレーズを「例年｛れいねん｝より」とします。

（２）「年」には人の年齢｛ねんれい｝を表｛あらわ｝す意味｛いみ｝があります。これは、「平成〇〇年」の「年」とは違｛ちが｝う意味です。また、人の年齢を表現｛ひょうげん｝する単位｛たんい｝（counter）として「歳｛さい｝」という漢字があります。

「歳」は常用漢字｛じょうようかんじ｝であって、その音読｛おんよ｝みは、「サイ」「セイ」となっております。
常用漢字では決｛き｝められていないが日常｛にちじょう｝使｛つか｝われている「歳」の読み方｛かた｝として、「とし」「とせ」「よわい」があります。これは[常用漢字表{じょうようかんじひょう}](http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/naikaku/pdf/joyokanjihyo_20101130.pdf)にない読み方として、「[表外読｛ひょうがいよ｝み](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12111089377)」と呼｛よ｝ばれておりますが、日本語を記述｛きじゅつ｝する上で役｛やく｝に立｛た｝っております。

例えば「年齢｛ねんれい｝は？ *How old are you?*」と尋｛たず｝ねるとき、一般｛いっぱん｝に「としは？」と言｛い｝います。これを漢字を使｛つか｝って書き表｛あらわ｝すとき、常用漢字表に従｛したが｝えば「年は？」が正{ただ}しいのですが、この文字列｛もじれつ｝を[読み手]{よみて}が見たとき、ＯＰの質問にあった混乱｛こんらん｝を引｛ひ｝き起｛お｝こす可能性｛かのうせい｝があると判断｛はんだん｝します。そこで、表外読みとは承知｛しょうち｝の上で、敢｛あ｝えて「歳{とし}は？（実際には振り仮名はつけません）」と書いて混乱を防ぐことがあります。

---

## EDIT

ＯＰの次のコメントを見て、少し情報を加える必要があると判断しました。

> That was a real struggle to read for someone who doesn't know the difference between とし and ねん ;)

付け加えようとする情報は２つです。

> 「年」が単独の漢字で使われたとき、
>   １）「年」をどう読むか。
>   ２）「年」の意味は何か。

１）**「年」という漢字が単独の単語として使われたときは、「とし」と読みます。** 例外は必ずありますが、例外を気にすることなく、「とし」と読んでください。その理由は「年｛ねん｝」という単語がないからです。
【例外】
- この「年」という漢字はどう読むの？
- 君はなん年{ねん}？（＝君は何年生ですか？）
- **年｛ねん｝に**何回台風が来ると思う？（＝１年に何回台風が来ると思う？）【この表現は多い】

２）「年」という漢字が単独の単語として使われたときの意味は、「１年という時、あるいはその単位」と「ある年齢、あるいは年齢の単位」の２つ。区別は前者は「属時（時に関係する）」、後者は「属人（人に関係する）」です。但し「飼い犬の年｛とし｝」という言い方があるので、「属動物、属生き物」の方が適切な表現かもしれない。

ＯＰの例題「飲み物の会社はいつもの年よりたくさん作っています。」に照らすと、漢字単独で使われているので読み方は「とし」、属人・属動物の要素がないので意味は「時に関する year」となります。

Comment: That was a real struggle to read for someone who doesn't know the difference between とし and ねん ;)

Answer (score 4):

The kanji 年 means 'year' on its own. It sometimes takes the meaning of 'old age', especially as part of the word 年上｛としうえ｝ ("years above").

As part of a longer composite Chinese-derived word you'd use the 音読{おんよ｝み of ねん as in 一年生｛いちねんせい｝.

As its own word it's common to read it with the 訓読{くんよ｝み of とし. In this case, because the context lends the Kanji's meaning to be closer to 'year' than 'old age', I would read it とし because the Kanji does not seem to be part of another word, and assume the meaning to be 'year' by the context of いつもの年｛とし｝ "the usual years".

Answer (score 3):

I would expect 年 to be read as とし、specifically because the kanji is alone. Also, in the specific word 年より、which means elderly, it would be read as としより。In most cases, when 年　is combined with another kanji, such as in 光年、or light years, it is read as こうねん。That being said, 毎年 can be read as まいとし with no problem.

I cannot answer the "to a fluent speaker" question accurately, because I am not one, but I would imagine that it would not cause much trouble for them.